# If $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly and $\sum |f_n|$ converges pointwise, does $\sum |f_n|$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Uniform convergence of $∑ f_n$ along with pointwise convergence of  $ ∑ | f_n(x)| $ 
>    implies
>   uniform convergence of $∑ | f_n(x)|$? If true, prove it; if not true, give a counterexample.

I don't think this is right but I have trouble thinking about a counterexample.
Could you please think of any? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: For $x\in [0,1],$ the power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}.$$

converges uniformly to $\ln(1+x)$ on $[0,1].$ That requires some proof (Dirichlet's theorem for uniform convergence will do it), but after all this is just a sketch.

Now let's restrict to $[0,1).$ Then this power series is absolutely convergent on $[0,1).$ But the absolute value series, namely

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n},$$

does not converge uniformly on $[0,1).$

Comment: Oh wait the absolutevalue series converges uniformly by Weistrass

Comment: I don't think so. You would need $x^n/n\le M_n$ for all $x\in [0,1)$  and  $\sum M_n<\infty.$ What would you propose for the $M_n?$

Comment: $\sum{x^n}$ is convergent and this is $M_n$

Comment: No, $M_n$ has be independent of $x.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. So this series is pointwise convergent, right?

Comment: Yes, the series is absolutely convergent at each $x\in [0,1).$